# Why am I getting an "ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression" when using Thymeleaf's safe navigation operator?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, ognl

For some reason I'm getting an `ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression` when using Thymeleaf's safe navigation operator (`${inter.someObj?.field}`). No issues if I get rid of the operator. Spring-boot 2.6.2, thymeleaf 3.0.14. Project is setup using Thymeleaf's OGNL and not the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` with SpEl apparently. Does somebody know why am I getting this? And (hopefully) how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://northcoder.com/post/thymeleaf-vs-spel-vs-ognl/ the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) is only available when using the Spring Expression Language:

> SpEL offers several enhancements which are not available in OGNL - and therefore not available in the Thymeleaf standard dialect. For example, it has the safe navigation operator, which provides a convenient way to handle null values when evaluating expressions.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the documentation, thanks. Changing to the `SpringTemplateEngine` inside `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` fixed this.